# MYSql CGI Script

Tags: python, cgi, cgi-bin

Below Code is my CGI Script, where am trying to do a insert Command.

```
#! C:\Python27\python.exe -u

import cgi
import MySQLdb
import xml.sax.saxutils


query = cgi.parse()
db = MySQLdb.connect(


host = "127.0.0.1",
user = "root",
passwd = "mysql123",
db = "welcome")

print 'Content-type: text/plain\n\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<result>'

try:
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("insert into welcome.registrations values ('test','test',now())")
print '\t<update>true</update>'
except:
print '\t<update>false</update>'


print "</result>"
```

when i run the go to the url - .com/cgi-bin/reg.cgi, am not finding any insert operation done in mysql DB

Comment: Are you seeing this 
print "</result>" getting printed

Comment: I meant there is some problem with your apache configuration

Comment: You might look into using a web lightweight framework such as [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) or [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/). Using cgi seems like a massive headache.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `db.commit()` after `c.execute()`.

Or you could do:

```
with db:
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("insert into welcome.registrations values ('test','test',now())")
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you do a db.commit() after every insert (or in the end, any will work ):

```
try:
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("insert into welcome.registrations values ('test','test',now())")
db.commit()
db.close() # Make sure you close the connection else multiple connections will result in hanging of mysql server.
```